# Converting 11-, 12- and 13-digit date to datetime in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, timestamp

I am solving the conversion date of birth in string format to datetime format in Power BI. Some dates are 11-digit, some 12-digit, some 13-digit, others have a "minus" sign at the beginning (yellowed examples).

[image]

If it is Unix time in ms, I created a custom column using the following formula according to mentioned video:

Datetime = #datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) + #duration(0, 0, 0, [TimeStamp] / 1000 )

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BY0WV05IeNk]

[image]

The obtained data of birth in datetime format looks good, but the logical meaning disappears (the age of employees does not correspond to specific job positions, e.g. age hire date of employees for a specific position - in the past - falls into the child's age).

Do you have a tip on another way to get the datetime please?
(If the procedure is correct, then the irrelevance of the input data can be considered, I guess.)

Thanks a lot.